# VimL: "use" composer to open class file, when cursor is on its name

Tags: vim

We know that composer know the path of class, in standard psr-0

```
map <F6>  :call ComposerKnowWhereCurrentFileIs()<CR>

function! ComposerKnowWhereCurrentFileIs()
    let l:currentWord = explode('<cword>')
    let l:command = "!grep " . l:currentWord . " vendor/composer -R | awk '{print $6}' | awk -F\' '{print $2}'"
    let l:fileName = system(l:command)
    let l:openFileCommand = 'tabe ' . l:fileName
    exec l:openFileCommand
endfunction
```

But, ... I see this output when I press  key

```
Error detected while processing function ComposerKnowWhereCurrentFileIs:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: explode
E15: Invalid expression: explode('<cword>')
line    2:
E121: Undefined variable: l:currentWord
E15: Invalid expression: "!grep " . l:currentWord . " vendor/composer -R | awk '
{print $6}' | awk -F\' '{print $2}'"
line    3:
E121: Undefined variable: l:command
E116: Invalid arguments for function system(l:command)
E15: Invalid expression: system(l:command)
line    4:
E121: Undefined variable: l:fileName
E15: Invalid expression: 'tabe ' . l:fileName
line    5:
E121: Undefined variable: l:openFileCommand
E15: Invalid expression: l:openFileCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `explode()` in Vimscript. You mean `expand()`.

Also, you either execute an external command via `system()`, **or** you use the `:!` command, but not both. So `"!grep "` should simply be `"grep "`.

Finally, you should make your parameter handling more robust against strange filenames. Use `shellescape(l:currentWord)` and `fnameescape(l:fileName)`.